# Redirect with Node.js and angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, redirect, express

I am having trouble trying to redirect POST requests using Node.js, Express and angular. I am aware there is a standard way of using forms as follows:

**index.ejs**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Redirect Example</title>
</head>
<body>
  <p>INDEX PAGE</p>
  <form action="/redirect" method="post">
    <button type="submit">CLICK</button>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**test.ejs**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Redirect Example</title>
</head>
<body>
  <p>YAY REDIRECTED</p>
</body>
</html>
```

**app.js**

```
var fs = require('fs');
var https = require('https');

var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');

var app = express();
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.render('index');
});

app.post('/redirect', function(req, res){
  res.redirect('/test');
});

app.get('/test', function(req, res) {
  res.render('test');
});

var port = process.env.PORT || 1337;
app.listen(port, function(){
  console.log('http://localhost:' + port + '/');
});
```

This method automatically redirects the page to the "test" route since it uses a form to handle the post request.

However using when I use an angular approach, the page does not automatically redirect. How would I do this?

**index.ejs**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="project">
<head>
  <title>Redirect Example</title>
  <script src="/javascripts/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="/javascripts/angular/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="/javascripts/angular/angular-route.js"></script>
  <script src="/javascripts/main.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="MainController">
    <button type="submit" ng-click="submit()">CLICK</button>
</body>
</html>
```

**main.js**

```
var app = angular.module('project', []);
app.controller('MainController', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {

  $scope.submit = function() {
    $http.post('/redirect');
  }
}]);
```

Answer (score 5):

Try keeping the redirection from within Angular, as Angular is meant to stay client-side in its own module. Like I said in a comment, you can send a status code from the server indicating the client to do a redirect.

For example, change your express endpoint to something like

```
app.post('/redirect', function(req, res){
    res.status(300).send({ redirect:"/test"});
});
```

And your Angular Controller to something like

```
var app = angular.module('project', []);
app.controller('MainController', ['$scope', '$http', '$window', function ($scope, $http, $window) {

  $scope.submit = function() {
    $http.post('/redirect').then(function(data, status){
      $window.location.href = data.redirect; 
    });
  }
}]);
```

This way you can specify the redirect address from within server-side code.

Edit: In addition, I think you would need a hashtag for your redirect in angular, unless you have HTML5 mode enabled.

Comment: I have been consistently using res.redirect here on a personal project and was getting frustrated as my browser was just rec'ving HTML in the console -- this is so incredibly helpful and makes complete sense -- thanks for your clear and great example -- I just added an if check ie, `if (data.redirect) { /* window location href change here */ }` and works flawlessly! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Routes created by node.js server are actual routes while AngularJS routing is based on hash (#) tags like -

Routes in **node.js** -

app.get('/myroute') will be like - http://localhost:8000/myroute

Routes in **AngularJS** -

'/myangroute' will be like - http://localhost:8000/#/myangroute

So coming back to your question, `$http.post('/redirect');` is not redirecting you but posting the data to `'/redirect'` route(defined at server end). For redirection use angularjs `$location` service.

Comment: Thanks Nesh, could you give a quick example on how I would use it for the code I have above?

Comment: Instead of actual redirect in `res.redirect('/test')` I usually prefer to send status code and then perform action in AngularJS

Comment: I agree with Nesh. Angular is meant to work alone in its own module as a client, so handle the redirect from inside angular. Change the express endpoint to instead return a status code and use something like `$window.location.href = value` to **redirect from inside of the success callback of the $http.post function**.

Comment: Right. I was doing that before but didn't like writing too much client side code for redirection. I like how using forms requires no client side code for redirection, so I guess that is what I was mainly looking for. Simple code you can write on the server side to redirect a request. But it looks like standard practice is to redirect on client side. Thanks for the help guys!

Comment: @slim1801 Actually AngularJS main purpose is to make SPA so if you are reloading the content and doing the whole page load ..it will not serve the purpose of using AngularJS